# Запятая перед "таким же как ты"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в предложении:

*Когда я был таким же молодым, как ты, и у меня кипела кровь.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед "таким же как ты" не нужна. Нужна перед "как".

Сравнительный оборот со словами *так(ой), как* (кто-то) разъединяется запятой: так(ой) - указательное слово.

[**ТАКОЙ (,) КАК,** *местоимение + союз*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oIKGAHDVGJoJ:new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum%3Flayout%3Ditem%26id%3D58_722%20&cd=3&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)

> По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в
>   основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
>
> *Он, рыжий человечек, может назвать **такие** имена, **как** Малянов Дмитрий Алексеевич, астроном, Губарь Захар Захарович, инженер, и
>   Снеговой Арнольд Павлович, химико-физик.* А. и Б. Стругацкие, За
>   миллиард лет до конца света. *Быть может, только **такие** люди,
>   **как** Шиллер, могли быть достойны ее любви.* К. Паустовский, Ручьи, где плещется форель. *Отчего же ты не старый, // А **такой, как** был
>   тогда?* А. Ахматова, Веет ветер лебединый... *«…Это в общем сон, но не
>   **такой, как** обычно»...* Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов. *Садись **такой, как** ты есть. Не принаряжайся.* Б. Пастернак, Доктор Живаго. *Дуб был точно **такой, как** в царскосельском саду.* Ю.
>   Тынянов. Кюхля. ***Такие, как*** ты, рождались во все эпохи кровавой
>   истории наших планет. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Трудно быть богом. *Теперь,
>   хлопче, скажу тебе, и бабы не **такие, как** прежде.* В. Короленко,
>   Лес шумит.
>
> Однако в некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а
>   перед словом «такой»:
>
> 1) если слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным:
>   *Погода **дождливая, такая как** осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была **мрачная, такая как** в старинных замках* (ср.: *Погода такая, как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была такая, как в старинных замках*);
>
> 2) если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед
>   рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не
>   требуется): *Туристы посетили старинные города, **такие как** Суздаль,
>   Владимир, Ростов Великий.*